# Can you determine the order of a generator in this group presentation?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, free-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Given the following group presentation $<x,y|2x+3y=0, 5x+2y=0>$ of an Abelian group, find the order of element x.

My follow up question: Is there a way to determine the order without finding some known group that the presentation is isomorphic to. I have tried to manipulate the relations and have found out 11x=0. Can I say that the order of x must divide 11?

Comment: Yes, it follows that the order of $x$ divides $11$.

Comment: You are asking too many questions at once. The answer to your final question is yes, if you have proved that $11x=0$, then the order o9f $x$ must divide $11$. But you still have to decide whether it is $1$ or $11$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the free abelian group $<X,Y> \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$.
Any element in $\mathbb{G}$, the group defined in the question, has the form $ax+by$, $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. So this question has something to do with grid, but this is not a necessary concept.

The definition relation of $\mathbb{G}$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3\\
5 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y 
\end{bmatrix} =0
$$
Note that neither row additions nor multiplying $-1$ changes the induced group. (But general scale multiplications would change the induced group). The matrix can transform to be
\begin{bmatrix}
-3 & 1\\
11 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
So $11x=0$ and $y = 3x$. Actually, this implies $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{11}$.